# determinant as product of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, jordan-normal-form

I was reviewing the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) page for determinants which states that for all complex matrices, the determinant is the product of its eigenvalues. However, isn't this true for real matrices as well, if we just consider them in the larger vector space $\mathbb{C^{n\times n}}$? Looking at the complex Jordan form (which won't necessarily exist in $\mathbb{R}$) it seems to be true.

Is there anything I am missing that would prevent the determinant of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}}$from being the product of its real and complex eigenvalues, like could there be an odd number of complex eigenvalues for a real matrix?

Comment: Complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients occur in [conjugate pairs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem)

Comment: Yep, just view real matrices as complex matrices. The determinant is the product of complex eigenvalues, counted with algebraic multiplicity. This follows from relating the constant term of the characteristic polynomial to its roots.

Comment: thank you everyone!

Comment: It is probably better to say that the determinant is the product of the roots of its characteristic polynomial (in an algebrqic closure of the field), reserving the word *eigenvalue* for actual eigenvalues.